# Is it secure to use window.origin with postMessage?

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, postmessage, window.location

When using postMessage it's important to define a targetOrigin to ensure we don't leak data to other sites.

It's equally important to check the origin when receiving a message to prevent other sites from triggering our scripts.

But, if we're just expecting to do this on our own domain, is there anything wrong with:

```
targetWindow.postMessage({message}, window.origin);
```

--

```
window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  if (e.origin == window.origin){
    //Trigger something
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a security expert, but [MDN recommends to check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Security_concerns) message's `origin` & possibly `source` properties. So, that's right to check it & we can consider it safe.

Now, the question starts to be:

> How safe is it to check the message's `origin` against the window's
> `origin`?

First of all, consider that there are 2 ways to check the `origin` of the window. The one you are trying to use is [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/origin) the alternative one is [window.location.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin).

I wouldn't use `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.origin` because it can be overwritten on client-side. Try it out:

```js
window.origin = 'https://www.example.com';
console.log(window.origin === 'https://www.example.com');
```

I don't think it's a direct security threat (though I'm not a security expert as I stated above), but given certain conditions, it can make it too easy to perform a successful attack.

`window.location.origin` might be a better choice because it is read-only & it cannot be modified on client-side. As a bonus, it has wider browser support.

So, I would use either `window.location.origin` or hard-code the URL as shown at MDN.

If hard-coding URL seems problematic because of testing, you could use environmental variables if your project uses modern building tools.

Comment: Hi Igor, many thanks for the post. My inclination would be that if someone had the access to change window.origin to their domain, then I think they'd already have enough access to wreak whatever havoc they wished! If there are browsers that support postMessage and not window.origin that would be relevant though. I can't find a support table. Can you? 
I think we probably do need a security expert to know for sure if there are any reasons not to do this.

Comment: @JamieG if you want a security advice, [there might be a better place to ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Jamie G
Doesnt really require a compromise at all.
You can use a debugger tool to inject a script that does it on pretty much any page.